# TFS Backup Fails - when it starts taking transactional backup

Tags: tfs, backup

I have scheduled TFS backup using TFS power tool. It was working fine till 10 days back. Now it started this... tried all the ways what am aware of but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this a while back, the issue is probably the Remote Connection Timeout setting in SQL Server (default 600), if you log onto your SQL Server box, go to the properties and update this (for the SQL Server instance your database is hosted in) to something a bit higher, you're probably safe to just double it for now.